# Mysql Document Store and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a requirement to use MySQL as NoSQL. I know that I can use MySQL as document store, but I have not found documentation about how to do it using Spring Boot. I have the connection with MySQL 8, but I need create some entities and work with some services. Anybody knows how to create entities and save them as documents in mysql using spring boot?

Comment: explore this *https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/* and *https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html*

Answer (score 0):

If you need store a json doc inside a MYSQL table using spring you need the spring-data project dependency that is a framework for SQL database use-cases (It docs is very intuitive). As an entity format you could declare the column format as a java String and it should works fine.